# Enabling high-dpi on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, macbook

I'm running Ubuntu in a VM (Parallels) on a Macbook Pro here.

One of the major issues I still have is to have Ubuntu running properly in high-dpi mode.

I have already fiddled with unity-tweak-tool to increase the text size. This does however not work for every application and the menubars, buttons, cursor etc. stay very small.

Is there a correct or recommended approach to enable high dpi on 14.10? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Displays -> Scale for menu and titlebars -> Move the slider up - may be as much as 2, adjust for your liking.

[image]

After doing this you may need to readjust the font size.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it has no effect, even after a reboot. This is a fresh installation with Parallels Tools installed.

Comment: It must be a bug with the vm then, it works on an installed ubuntu